# How to clear description of more than 100 songs in a step

Tags: itunes, music

I want to clear description of more than 100 songs. It is tiring to clear one by one. Can I clear the description in other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Select all tracks at once
- Open information window
- Tick mark on (empty) description field (or any other field you want to clear on all tracks)
- Click OK

Comment: Do you mean "tick mark on (empty) description field"?

Comment: yes, whatever field you want to clear on all songs.

Comment: Where is "description" in the information dialog?

Comment: @jtheletter ITunes has changed UIs significantly between 2012 and today, so it might very well be that things work differently today. Will check when I‘m back in front of a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in AppleScript, select the files you want to change, and run. You can reuse the code for updating other information such as 'composer' or 'comment' by changing 'description' below.

```
tell application "iTunes"
set sel to selection
if sel is not {} then
    repeat with this_track in sel
        try
            tell this_track to set description to ""
        end try
    end repeat
end if
end tell
```